# Should I publish my Flutter App if Im not 100% sure about its security?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a flutter delivery app for (3) months, its now 99% complete. I am planning to make this app available just within my city, However I am worried that someone will take time to extract/decompile and reverse engineer my app to extract the customer info(fullName,Address,tel.no) that I have storing in cloud firestore, So far I have taken all the security measures I can think of:

1.) [Using pro-guard and pro-guard rules](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421)

2.) [Obfuscating Dart code](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate)

3.) [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules#:%7E:text=Firebase%20Security%20Rules%20work%20by,allowing%20read%20or%20write%20access.)

However none of this can protect my users data 100% not just like big app companies who manage data on their server side infrastructure which I dont have resources and the know how. What I am really worried about is when they reverse engineer my app they can extract all users I have then I have to face consequence or lawsuit from my users.

Comment: Have you tried to `reverse engineer` by yourself on your app? What type data are not secure?

Comment: I didnt, however app reverse engineering is always there. Like how we have modded apps and paid apps that can be downloaded for free due to the fact that someone decompile and set "paidUser = true;" on the modded app. Here is a simple article for that  https://medium.com/dwarsoft/how-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-application-in-3-easy-steps-dwarsoft-mobile-880d268bdc90  more over with the right tools and right hacking knowledge.  That someone can change my firebase method or create his own to fetch UsersData from the firebase. Not all can do that but if someone will then consequences are high